# GoogleFit REST API coming empty

Tags: google-fit

Today I made a GET request (https://www.googleapis.com/fitness/v1/users/me/dataSources) to one of the users of my database and the data came like:

```
{"dataSource": []}
```

And the user showed me the dashboard on fit.google.com and there is step data there. She is connecting the same account on fit and on my app.

Any idea of what could be happening? My other users are coming with data, but this one is empty.

Thank you

Comment: So what is the complete request that you are using? Did you receive any kind of error? Can you please elaborate more your question.

Comment: Well, basically what I wrote is what I did. I got the user's token and requested a GET on the link. And I received an empty dataSource. For other users, the dataSource didn't come empty.

Comment: i solved it by asking the user to disconnect and connect again. It means, to receive a new token from google and store it again. Very strange, I'm still analysing to check what happened.

Comment: Thanks, @ASP . But i could implement these importing already, they problem is aparently an atypical response from Google Fit.